# Web-app or Windows app to show speed of regex (regular expression)

Tags: gratis, regex

I am looking for a gratis web-app or Windows app that shows me the speed of computing a regex on one or more sample strings.

The speed can be actual speed, or a relative speed as compared to a standardized index.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [python](https://python.org/) with the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or [`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex) libraries you can simply use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) library or even easier in [iPython](https://ipython.org/) or [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) you can use the [%time and %timeit](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling/) magics along with the `%prun` magic.

All of the software mentioned above is Free, Gratis & Open Source, and available for multiple platforms including Windows.